# How do I position the text in a button?

Tags: html, css, button, position

Suppose I have a button:

HTML

```
<input type="button" class = "button" value="Click here"
```

CSS

```
.button {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
```

This button is going to be big and I dont want to position the text in the center, I want to position it in the center top. how do I do it?

Comment: text-align + line-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text-align with line-height based on the height you give to the button

Comment: how could I implement this using my code? if I put this as the html:<p><input class="button" type="button" value="Events" /></p> and this as the css .button {height: 300px; width: 300px;line-height: 50px; text-align:middle; it does not do anything

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `height` `width`, use `padding`

```
padding: 0px 150px 300px 150px;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however my plan is to put an image in the button as well so if I put what you say it would move the image rather than the image. Could you use text-align and line-height like the comment below?

Comment: If you want to put image to the button, then do this       `padding: 0px 150px 300px 150px;
    background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30876/css-button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

if you want to add some gap from the top, you can add padding-top.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use **flex** rules for a `.button`.

```css
.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class = "button" value="Click here">
```

Comment: Nice. But how could I lower it a bit? I mean the text

Comment: i wrote in the answer above. take a look

Comment: @JohnMakati, Why don't you use a button tag with text inside like this - `<button><p>text</p></button>` ?

Comment: @JohnMakati, Show the desired end result.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add some padding to make the Text lower